# If (BOOL) in Objective C: unused variable

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, boolean, ios6, cgrect

In an implementation of a CGRect, I attempt this:

```
BOOL didStartPressing = NO;
if ( didStartPressing) {int nmax=5;}
else{int nmax=500;}

for (int n=1; n<nmax; n=n+1){ *... working code that draws some circles ....*     }
```

This gives yellow warnings about "unused variable nmax" in the first part above
and red warnings about "use of undeclared variable nmax." for the for loop.
If  however I simply replace the first three lines above with

```
int nmax=500;
```

I get a lovely picture that I drew in CGRect.

Greatest of thanks for help, as I'm complete noob up against the hard wall of learning curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've limited the *scope* of `nmax` to the braces after the `if` and the `else`. So you have two variables with that name, neither of which is visible to the `for` loop. To solve, move the declaration to the outer scope and simply assign to the variable in the `if`/`else` scopes:

```
int nmax = 0;   // the = 0 is optional in this case because all code
                // paths assign a value to nmax
BOOL didStartPressing = NO;
if (didStartPressing) {
    nmax=5;
} else {
    nmax=500;
}

for (int n=1; n<nmax; n=n+1) {
    /*... working code that draws some circles ....*/
}
```

Comment: **Thanks** immensely for the tip, makes sense now.  Is there a straight "C" way to allow a int variable's value to be changed by a UIButton method, or does one have to make such a variable a full-fledged Objective C _object_?

Comment: You mean something like `- (IBAction)changeIntValue:(id)sender { myIntVariable = 12345; }`?

Comment: Jonathan, that, too, gives "Use of undeclared identifier nmax".

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan, will brush up on that more.

Comment: Successfully got the code to increase as per (nmax=nmax+100) upon the touch of a button by adding an instance variable.  Now just trying to redraw my rect, modified from a tute that apparently didn't declare it in the interface. But I'm good, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a C language thing.  The scope of a variable that's declared inside a pair of braces is only the section inside the braces.  That means you have two different variables, both called `nmax` and each limited to its section of the if/else statement.

You can make it work with:

```
int nmax = 500;
if ( didStartPressing) {
    nmax=5;
}
```

Look at a book on C programming for more details.